# UITableView showing inconsistent number of rows compared to data source

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to make a UITableView present a determined number of rows for a section, but even when I verify that its data source is returning x number of rows for numberOfRowsInSection, the table view shows x-1.

The exception to this unexpected behavior is if the numberOfRowsInSection is less than 3.

I've even put a breakpoint in cellForRowAtIndexPath and I confirmed it's being called for the row that is not appearing.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == SectionNumber_One) {
        return 6;
    } else {
        return self.numberOfProjectRows; // This returns x, but x-1 rows are being shown
    }
}
```

For example, if self.numberOfProjectRows is 5, only 4 rows are shown for the second section.

If I increase it manually to 6, it shows 5 rows but the data that should be in the 5th position, isn't there.

It doesn't seem to be related to screen size as I tested it on an iPad with same results.

Why is this happening? Is there some other possible modifier of the number of rows in a section?

I'm attaching an screenshot if it's of any help.

[image: UITableView screenshot]

**EDIT -** Here are my delegate methods:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Cell with reuse identifier setup

    if (section == SectionNumber_One) {
        // cell setup for section one that's showing up ok
    } else if (section == SectionNumber_Two) {
        UITextField *projectField = cell.projectTextField;
        if ([self.userProjectKeys count] > row) {
            projectField.text = self.availableProjects[self.userProjectKeys[row]];
        }
    }
    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Hide the password row for existing users
    if (indexPath.row == FieldTag_Password && ![self.user.key vol_isStringEmpty]) {
        return 0.0f;
    } else {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show some more of your viewcontroller code?

Comment: The problem is probably not in your Datasource methods, but your Delegate methods. If you do not return a correct height for the cell, it won't show up. **You need to add the code to your actual delegate methods to your question** where you set the Height of the cell if you need further help. It doesn't matter if you write 1000 cells in your datasource. If you don't return the height, they wont show up. You should also add code to your cellForRow methods.

Comment: @Sneak Thank you very much!!! You nailed it. I changed the height of a row thinking only about section 0, and forgot it would modify section 1 too.

Comment: @jcabrera Glad to help, I will add it as an answer if you want to accept it so the community can see it as solved and the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably not in your Datasource methods, but your **Delegate** methods, [tableView(_:heightForRowAt:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614998-tableview).

If you do not **return a correct height** for the cell, it won't show up.

It doesn't matter if you write 1000 cells in your datasource. If you don't return the height, they wont show up.

Answer (score 0):

You are not comforming to the MVC pattern in implementing the table. You must return the count of the tableView's datasource, not variables of it.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == SectionNumber_One) {
        return 6;
    } else {
        return [_displayingArray count]; // <-- here
    }
}
```

If you want different items for each sections, then declare different datasource (ie array) for each of them.

**EDIT**: Even returning constant 6 is dangerous in the other section - you ought to add items to another fixed array and return that array's count in this delegate.

Comment: self.numberOfProjectRows is equal to [self.displayingArray count] + 1 because I need it to show one more empty row. Returning constant 6 was just for testing. Thank you!

Comment: That is where you are mistaken. If you want to add one more row, then you must add an empty item on self.displayingArray. It is better that way. Always do changes on the datasource, not on the delegates.